# how to convert setter to List when the parameter is not list?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

The reason for not using `List<Integer> purchase_item_cart` because of problem in mybatis mapping and the solution i can think of is convert it to List

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Client {
    
    private Integer client_guest_id;
    private String client_guest_name;
    private String client_guest_email;
    
    private Integer purchase_item_cart;
    private ProductEntity productEntity;
    
    }
```

I dont know how to convert setter `purchase_item_cart` to List

```
    
    public List<Integer> returnasList(Integer integer){
        
        
        
        
        return null;
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying you want a singleton list?  Such as the one returned by the [`Collections.singletonList` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-)?

Comment: I have return method here for `getter` List from other Class. The problem is the setter is not List to this Class, so its not compatible. The solution i been searching is convert it to `List` while not changing `private Integer purchase_item_cart` to List if change it to `List` my mapping in Mybatis will error.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem just disregard this, I just found out that Mysql cant insert list of data in one column for Integer